# How do I find blocks of text ending with "!!", while still allowing "!" characters in Regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have a peculiar use case where I need to detect paragraphs that end in `!!`. Normal occurrences of `!` (a single one) is fine in the paragraph, but the block ends when `!!` is found.

For example:

```
test foo bar !!
longer paragraph this time!
goes on and on
and then stops !!
```

Should be detected as two separate matches, one covering the first line, and another (separate) covering lines 2, 3 and 4. This brings it to a total of 2 matches.

(Preferably it should work with multiline-mode, as it's part of a larger regex that employs this mode.)

How would I accomplish this? I tried `[^!!]*` which to me says, find as many non-`!!` characters as possible, but I'm not sure how to leverage that, and worse yet it still finds single occurrences of `!`.

Comment: Which is the language you are in?

Comment: I'm using PHP currently.

Answer (score 1):

There is a common idiom in regular expressions that is used for escape sequences. (Like "\n" in a string.) You can use the same concept here.

The trick is to match either NOT the first character, or the first character followed by a valid second character.

In your case, that would be:

```
(?:     # this is a package, either A or B, choose one
 [^!]   # Not a bang
 |      # or
 ![^!]  # Bang, followed by not-a-bang
)
```

This pair of alternatives describes all the characters in your paragraph. So you can repeat it either 0 times (*) or one-or-more times (+) depending on what you are doing in the rest of your pattern.

```
# All together:
(?:[^!]|![^!])*    # zero or more
(?:[^!]|![^!])+    # one or more
```

(Obviously, you can match '!!' at the end if you like...)

Comment: Actually, you *must* match the `!!` at the end.  If you don't, the second match will start at the second `!` on the first line. See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nB3hA0/1).  You could add a start-of-line anchor, too.  That's even better, because it stops it matching the line separator at the beginning of the second match.

Comment: How would I then modify this so that it would find the last block, but it doesn't have to end with `!!` (e.g.: in the original example, if there was just another two lines of text?)

Comment: I'd suggest changing the match for the end-marker. Try something like `(?:!!|\z)` - that should match either a trailing !! or the end of the subject string (multiline mode blocks using $).

Answer (score 1):

```
^([!]?[^!]+[!]?[^!]+)*[!]{2}$/gm
```

This regex worked for me. It ensures any single ! characters are separated by non-! characters, but there don't have to be any single ! characters. It worked on multiline mode. This also has the added benefit of extracting the text that comes before an occurrence of "!!" since I assume you want to work with it.

```
/^([!]?[^!]+[!]?[^!]+)*.?[!]{2}$|^([!]?[^!]+[!]?[^!]+)*[^!]?[!]?$/gm
```

This slightly longer regex captures text that occurs after the final !! (ie, if the file has text between !! and EOF). I wouldn't recommend using the capturing groups though as on my regex checker, they didn't seem to work properly (that may have just been an implementation glitch, however, as the capturing groups look like they should work properly).

Comment: How would I then modify this so that it would find the last block, but it doesn't have to end with `!!` (e.g.: in the original example, if there was just another two lines of text?)

Comment: It's possible, but it messes up the capturing groups. I edited my answer to include this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
([\w\s!]+?\!{2})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aS1pR3/1)

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-15]  `test foo bar !!`
MATCH 2
1.  [15-76] `
longer paragraph this time!
goes on and on
and then stops !!`
```

or

```
(?:\n?([\w\s!]+?)\s?\!{2})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aS1pR3/2)

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-12]  `test foo bar`
MATCH 2
1.  [16-73] `longer paragraph this time!
goes on and on
and then stops`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following regex using lookahead

**VERSION #1**

```
/(?<=!!|^).*?(?=!!)/gms
```

Please see https://regex101.com/r/cQ0wC0/2

Result should be

> OUTPUT:
>
> - test foo bar
> - longer paragraph this time!
>     goes on and on
>     and then stops

**VERSION #2**

Since OP want to capture last paragraph of text after `!!` even it's not ending with bang signs.

```
/(?<=!!|^).*?(?=!!)|(?<=!!).*$/gms
```

Please see demo https://regex101.com/r/cQ0wC0/4

> INPUT:

```
test foo bar !!
longer paragraph this time!
goes on and on
and then stops !!
longer paragraph this time!
goes on and on
```

> OUTPUT:
>
> - test foo bar
> - longer paragraph this time!
>     goes on and on
>     and then stops
> - longer paragraph this time!
>     goes on and on

Comment: How would I then modify this so that it would find the last block, but it doesn't have to end with `!!` (e.g.: in the original example, if there was just another two lines of text?)

Comment: You can definitely do that by modifying regex little bit. I tailored this regex to capture what are you asking in your question. If you have some edge cases, please mention in your post with supported text.

Comment: @DougSmith, see if updated regex **VERSION #2** meets your requirement